# Test REST service using Scala Lift

Tags: scala, rest, automated-tests, lift

I built a simple Scala Lift application with REST endpoint.

I want to write some tests. But Lift's documentation is horrible.

Everyone points to this 2011 gist https://gist.github.com/heralight/2235088

Can anyone tell me how to write a simple test? I need something like the gist example:

```
"process a JSON RestHelper Request" withReqFor("http://foo.com/api/info.json") in { req =>
      (WebSpecSpecRest(req)() match {
        case Full(JsonResponse(_, _, _, 200)) => true
        case other => failure("Invalid response : " + other); false
      }) must_== true
    }
```

I found that Lift has its WebSpec, can I use that? (WebSpec's doc is not there https://www.assembla.com/wiki/show/liftweb/WebSpec)

Or can anybody point me to a tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

Probably best to ask on the Lift mailing list. However, saying that Lift's documentation is horrible isn't going to go over well (read the community guidelines before posting), especially when the documentation does seem to cover what you are asking for: https://www.assembla.com/spaces/liftweb/wiki/Mocking_HTTP_Requests

To answer your question: I haven't done this in a while. Back in the ESME project days, we used TestKit along with Specs to test the API. Here's the relevant file: https://github.com/apache/esme/blob/akka/src/test/scala/org/apache/esme/api/API2Test.scala

I suspect that this approach using TestKit to post against your Lift app may actually be what you're looking for. TestKit is documented at http://liftweb.net/api/26/api/#net.liftweb.http.testing.TestKit for the 2.6 version of Lift and looks like it is still included in the upcoming 3.0 release, so I suspect it is the way to go.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't want to offend any of the authors. But my conclusion was based on the link the you passed, I read that doc many times.

Comment: Got it - that wasn't the link you had in your post though, so assumed you hadn't seen it. I guess the question is what you have done so far. I also think you might want to check out TestKit. I will include a couple of links in the post above.